# Custom Server Adapter - Eclipse resources

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

As we all know, we can create custom server using eclipse programmatically by either using generic server adapter or custom server adapter.

My question, is there any tutorial/docs/articles etc available for "Custom Server Adapter" implementation? I searched a lot but not able to get major informations, I found one link:
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/server/api_concepts.html
But it's almost 8 years old, I am not sure if there is any significant changes in those concepts.

Currently we are trying to implement a custom server for eclipse, since it is a server based on node.js, I think "Generic server framework" doesn't work, so only options for us is to roll out custom adapter.

So is there anyway I can learn about the same apart from Tomcat custom server adapter implementation? Which I am finding bit difficulty in understanding the some of the concepts.

Comment: I am not able to understand how it is "Too Broad"? Just I am asking a resources where I can find information regarding custom server development. @Andrew Barber.

Comment: asking for resources it's not on topic. you ate also asking for a tutorial; that's *way* too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at jetty-wtp plugin, seems to me that it is a bit simpler than tomcat adapter. 
(other option are jboss as plugin - rather difficult to understand, maybe heroku plugin - not really sure)

You can find jetty here: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.wtp

Comment: You don't need to add signatures below your post - your user card is posted automatically.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look :)